# Python regular expressions (regex), convert JSON to text file for parsing

Tags: python, regex, filenames, glob

I annotated some video frames with VGG annotator that gives me the annotations in `JSON` format and want to parse it to extract values I need (x, y coordinates).
I have looked at other postings on this site but nothing seems to match my case as the length of the filename changes, ie. frame number 0 to 9 then 10 to 99, 100 to 999, 1000 to 9999, increasing by one digit.

I have tried `import glob` and using wildcard ranges, single characters and asterisks.

My code now:

```
#Edited 
while count < 1200:
    x = data[key]['regions']['0']['shape_attributes']['cx']
    y = data[key]['regions']['0']['shape_attributes']['cy']
    pts = (x, y)
    xy.append(pts)
    count += 1

f = open("coordinates.txt", "w")
f.write(xy)
f.close()
```

JSON looks like:

```
        "shape_attributes": {
          "name": "point",
          "cx": 400,
          "cy": 121
        },
        "region_attributes": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "frame48.jpg78647": {
    "fileref": "",
    "size": 78647,
    "filename": "frame48.jpg",
    "base64_img_data": "",
    "file_attributes": {},
    "regions": {
      "0": {
        "shape_attributes": {
          "name": "point",
          "cx": 404,
          "cy": 114
        },
        "region_attributes": {}
      }
    }
```

Edit: I am going to convert the JSON to `.txt` file and parse that to get my values as I have no idea how to do so directly now.

I tried converting to string and parsing the string per below:
This did the job of getting x, y coordinates (3 digit ints) only appended to a list which I am going to convert to a list of tuples of (x,y) and print to a text file for use later as labels for a neural network where I'm tracking coordinates of a tennis ball on tennis matches on TV.

```
xy.append(re.findall(r'\b\d\d\d\b', datatxt))
```

Comment: It looks like you dont have the key `[f-r]*` in the dict. Are you sure you have it?

Comment: @balderman I was just trying to pick up the key that starts with f, ie. `'frame48.jpg78647'`.  So basically I want to wildcard so it's `frame` + `wc` + `.` + `jpg` + `wc` where `wc` stands for wildcard.

Comment: if you want to get a value from a dictionary you need yo know the exact key. This is how dictionary works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't wildcard keys in a dictionary. Do you actually care about the keys at all - are there entries you want to ignore, or are you happy to have any/all of them?

If the keys are unimportant, then take `data.values()` which will be a list of the dictionaries, and you can go through the first 1,200 entries of that.

If there are keys not in the format you give, then loop through them and check they match first:

```py
for key in data.keys():
    m = re.match('frame(\d+).jpg(\d+)$', key)
    if not m: continue
    f1, f2 = map(int, m.groups())
    if f1<0 or f1>1199 or f2<10000 or f2>99999: continue
    x = data[key]['regions']['0']['shape_attributes']['cx']
    y = data[key]['regions']['0']['shape_attributes']['cy']
    ...
```

Comment: @M Somerville, I want all of them for now.  I think your answer is most likely correct because I was able to print out ` f1 0, f2 39641` for the first key which is correct but now I am getting a key error on the `0`:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse-json.py", line 20, in <module>
    x = data[key]['regions']["0"]['shape_attributes']['cx']
KeyError: '0'`

Comment: That error tells you that `data[key]` dictionary has a `regions` key but the `data[key]['regions']` dictionary does not then have a `"0"` key. That is beyond the scope of your question, you will have to deal with checking the right parts exist if that is not always the case.

Comment: Seeing your edit (please accept the answer, in that case), you are again trying to use a wildcard in a key - that will not work.

Comment: @M Somerville, sorry.  Would you happen to know why the print statement with key `0` works and then it does not work in the loop when trying to extract value to `x`?

Comment: Not with the information you have provided. Your KeyError in the question is because you are using a wildcard; your one above - are you *sure* you are printing out the same row that you are processing in the loop? Why not, in the loop, print out the row being processed and see what that contains? Do your debugging in the code that is going wrong, not somewhere else where it might not match. Break down your statements into smaller parts and see precisely where it goes wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194637/discussion-between-mlstudent33-and-m-somerville).